# Import data to excel from rails URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, excel, odata

I want to import data to Excel from my rails URL. I have written an action to serve JSON data for the http request URL.

But when I try to import in excel using Power Query -> From other Sources -> From OData Feed I  am not getting any data instead I got an error 
`[DataFormat.Error] OData: The given URL neither points to an OData service or a feed: 'http://<server ip>:3000/test1/test2/test.json'.`

From the OData Documentation [here](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/json-format/),
I responded JSON data as `{ "d" : { "key": "value"} }`. But that doesn't seem to help. I got the same issue.

```
def test
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do 
      render :json => { "d" => { "key" => "value"} }
    end
  end
end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Power Query ->  From other Sources -> From OData Feed, you should provide the URL like http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories but not with a .json suffix. 
If you are trying to import direct from a JSON result file of OData service, you should use Power Query -> From File -> From Text